# How to downgrade python from 3.7 to 3.5?

Tags: python, windows, eclipse, pydev

I wanted to control a circuit board but some functions don't work for me.

A friend of mine has used Python 3.5 long time ago and the same code worked for him. So I wanted to downgrade from 3.7 to 3.5 to check if this will work.

I just found some downgrade methods with Anaconda, but I do not use Anaconda. Is there a method to downgrade without uninstalling all of my software plugins and reinstalling?

I am using Python 3.7 x64 on Windows 10 64b.

Comment: I'd be surprised if downgrading from 3.7 to 3.5 would fix the issues, instead you should describe whatever "don't work for me" means.

Comment: Yes, I'd be surprised aswell, but I just copy and pasted his code for the same board. The code did not work for me. I had no output.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need 3.7 again later, I would advise you to create an Anaconda environment with 3.5, do your business there, and keep the default the most updated as possible.

```
conda create -n yourenvname python=3.5 anaconda
```

then activate it with:

```
conda activate yourenvame
```